# How to move controls on Canvas at runtime in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to move control which generated at runtime and want to move on canvas in WPF.

I want to build application like Report generater(Not Exactly like Crystal Report).
but want to build something that I can put controls(`Label,TextBox,RichTextBox,Image Control` etc.) on canvas(WPF) and move then on canvas.

I am looking for moving control on canvas regardlessly, and capture position on canvas so that I can produce report in ( XPS or PDF) format. I dont have problem to Produce report.

I only face problem to move control and add `TextBlock` and `ImageControl` at runtime.

I really need guidance on it.

Is it any one have idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are able to add a Label at runtime? Show the code that is and the code that is not working. Much easier to answer with some concrete code.

Comment: How does it need to move?  Do you want to be just setting the location to some other value?  Do you want to be re-ordering items?  What determines the new location of each Control?

Comment: Place is a better word than move.  When I read the title I thought you wanted animation.

Answer (score 2):

You can get and set the left coordinate of a element on a Canvas through

```
Canvas.GetLeft(element) and Canvas.SetLeft(element, number)
```

There are also

```
Canvas.GetTop/Canvas.SetTop, Canvas.GetRight/Canvas.SetRight, Canvas.GetBottom/Canvas.SetBottom and Canvas.GetZIndex/Canvas.SetZIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

## WPF : Windows Presentation Foundation | C Sharp : C#

#### Moving Controls Using( [System.Windows.Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thickness) )

---

```
//Variables ----------------------
static System.Boolean MMove = false;
static System.Windows.Point MPoint1;
static System.Windows.Point MPoint2;
static System.Windows.Controls.Control MyControl = null;
static System.Windows.Controls.Canvas MyCanvas = null;
```

> [?] **static** variables required to accomplish moving controls in application;
> --- *MyCanvas* must be specified when your application starts; (or whenever before use)

---

```
//MouseEvents --------------------
yourControl.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MouseDown);
yourControl.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler(MouseUp);
yourControl.PreviewMouseMove += new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(MouseMove);
```

> [?] **Mouse Events** to be assigned to your control;

---

```
//MouseDown EventHandler ---------
static void MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is UserControl1)
    {
        //get control clicked
        MyControl = (UserControl1)sender;

        //get coordinates
        MPoint1 = e.GetPosition(MCanvas);
        MPoint2 = e.GetPosition(MyControl);

        //update coordinates
        MPoint1.X -= MyControl.Margin.Left + MPoint2.X;
        MPoint1.Y -= MyControl.Margin.Top + MPoint2.Y;

        //prevent mouse loosing focus of the control
        System.Windows.Input.Mouse.Capture(MyControl);

        //enable move indicator
        MMove = true;
    }
}
```

---

```
//MouseMove EventHandler ---------
static void MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (sender is UserControl1) {
        //check move indicator
        if (MMove == true)
        {
            //get control moved
            MyControl = (UserControl1)sender;

            //get container pointer
            var currentPoint = e.GetPosition(MCanvas);

            //check which mouse button is pressed
            if (e.LeftButton == System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                //update control margin thickness
                MyControl.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(
                    currentPoint.X - MPoint1.X - MPoint2.X,
                    currentPoint.Y - MPoint1.Y - MPoint2.Y,
                    MyControl.Margin.Right,
                    MyControl.Margin.Bottom
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
//MouseUp EventHandler ---------
static void MouseUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MMove = false;
    MyControl = null;
    System.Windows.Input.Mouse.Capture(null);
}
```

> [?] **EventHandler** used to perform logics for moving controls;

---

Comment: **[!]** Make Sure your Project Reference are included the following Assembly:
**PresentationCore;
PresentationFramework;
System;
System.Windows;
System.Xaml;
WindowsBase;**